# Shouldn't default of a ternary condition of a nullable target type be null (regardless of the type in consequent/alternative)?

Tags: c#, nullable, default-value

Consider the following example:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid? g2 = Guid.NewGuid();

Guid? defaultGuid = false ? g : default; //#1 result is 000...
Guid? defaultNullableGuid = false ? g2 : default; //result is null
```

Shouldn't default return the default value of the target type aka `Guid?` when using a [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)?

Instead the ternary condition tries to find out the target type itself using consequent/alternative and cast the result to the target type.

I ran into this problem when I refactored the target type from `Guid` to `Guid?` and my unit tests started to fail using `var guid = Guid.NewGuid()` as consequent/alternative part of the ternary conditional operator.

Comment: `false ? g : default` is of type `Guid` (type of `g`), this is why it results in `000...` instead of `null`. The fact that you assign this result to a `Guid?` variable is irrelevant

Comment: You can use `default(Guid?)` instead of `default` if you want "correct" behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `Guid?` is `null`. Indeed, this is true of any nullable value type as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

> The default value of a nullable value type represents null, that is, it's an instance whose Nullable.HasValue property returns false.

Further, the specification says this about ternaries:

The run-time processing of a conditional expression of the form b ? x : y consists of the following steps:

First, b is evaluated, and the bool value of b is determined:

- If an implicit conversion from the type of b to bool exists, then this implicit conversion is performed to produce a bool value.
- Otherwise, the operator true defined by the type of b is invoked to produce a bool value.
- If the bool value produced by the step above is true, then x is evaluated and converted to the type of the conditional expression, and this becomes the result of the conditional expression.
- Otherwise, y is evaluated and converted to the type of the conditional expression, and this becomes the result of the conditional expression.

Important to note: in this case, the default literal infers its type from the consequent, which is why you get the default `Guid` value in the first case. You can verify this by using `var` instead of explicitly stating a type in the two ternaries.